# Where can I get SQL Server 2000 Cumulative patch 8.00.2283?

Tags: sql-server

There are a number of good sites with versions and they list 8.00.2283 as downloadable but I can't find it anywhere.  I can find other cumulative patches but not 2283.

Comment: You should be looking for a different patch. It's called SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the KB from Microsoft:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971524/

You'll need to request the hotfix here:  http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=971524&kbln=en-us

I found this from from http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

Ooh, Itanium based SQL Server! I never got to work on one of those.... :(

The download works for me here:
http://support.microsoft.com/?Kbid=971524

The link came from:
http://www.sqlsecurity.com/FAQs/SQLServerVersionDatabase/tabid/63/Default.aspx